# coVerify fails when running multiple tests but succeeds if the test is run alone

Tags: spring-boot, mockk

I am using open weather map to get weather data. For this I call the api like this:

```
            openWeatherMapAPI.oneCall().historical()
                .byCoordinateAndTimestamp(
                    Coordinate.of(latitude.toDouble(), longitude.toDouble()),
                    startDateTime.toEpochSecond()
                )
                .language(Language.ENGLISH)
                .unitSystem(UnitSystem.METRIC)
                .retrieve()
                .asJava()
```

To mock this I use

```
        mockkConstructor(OpenWeatherMapClient::class)
        coEvery {
            anyConstructed<OpenWeatherMapClient>().oneCall()
                .historical().byCoordinateAndTimestamp(any(), any())
                .language(Language.ENGLISH)
                .unitSystem(UnitSystem.METRIC)
                .retrieve()
                .asJava()
        } returns testUtilsImplementation.getSuccessfulHistoricalWeatherResponse()
```

And to verify calls this:

```
        coVerify(exactly = 5) {
            anyConstructed<OpenWeatherMapClient>().oneCall()
                .historical().byCoordinateAndTimestamp(any(), any())
                .language(Language.ENGLISH)
                .unitSystem(UnitSystem.METRIC)
                .retrieve()
                .asJava()
        }
```

If I run this test alone, everything is fine but when I run multiple tests at the same time the coVerify fails.

`Verification failed: call 1 of 7: OpenWeatherMapClient(mockkConstructor<OpenWeatherMapClient>()).oneCall()) was not called`

The things I dont understand are:

- I would expect it to fail because of too many calls. But according to the message it isnt even called once
- where is the 7 coming from?
- Adding `unmockkConstructor(OpenWeatherMapClient::class)` or `unMockAll()` or `clearAllMocks()` changes nothing

Can anyone point me in a direction?